# CDI producer reached once

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I've created this producer:

```
@RequestScoped
public class StripeWebHookProducer {

    private static String HEADER_SIGNATURE = "Stripe-Signature";

    @Inject @Context private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Produces
    public Event getStripeEvent() {
        Event result = null;
        //...
        return result;
    }
}
```

As you can see it's scoped at `@RequestScoped`, so as far I've been able to figure out it should be created each time a request is reached on server.

I'm injecting it on my servlet:

```
@WebServlet(...)
public class StripeWebhook extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject private Event paymentEvent;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            switch (this.paymentEvent.getEventType())
            {
                case customer_subscription_trialwillend:
                    break;
                case customer_subscription_updated:
                    break;
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            doGet(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Nevertheless, `StripeWebHookProducer.getStripeEvent` is reached only once. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you mismatched annotations on class/bean and on producer method.
The thing is, producer method has to be placed inside some CDI bean. In your case this bean is `StripeWebHookProducer` and you have it `@RequestScoped` annotation. That's perferctly fine, however, it seems accidental so you might want to re-think that and use another one such as `@ApplicationScoped` or `@Dependent`

Now the producer method itself. The outcome of producer **is not affected by annotations on the CDI bean where the producer resides**. Instead, it is defined by annotation on that method. Here is some code with explanation.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyBeanWithProducer {
  @Produces
  @Dependent
  public ProducedBean produceIt() {
  }
}
```

The above sample is a CDI bean `MyBeanWithProducer` with application scope. It containts a producer method capable of creating another CDI bean, `ProducedBean`, which will have scope `@Dependent`. Note that the scope of produced bean differs from the scope of `MyBeanWithProducer`. If you define no scope on the producer method, it is `@Dependent` by default.

So, what you probably want in your app might look like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped // ensures there is only one instance of this bean in your app; assuming you have have no other request based logic here
public class StripeWebHookProducer {

    private static String HEADER_SIGNATURE = "Stripe-Signature";

    @Inject @Context private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped // this will make sure this bean is created on every request anew
    public Event getStripeEvent() {
        Event result = null;
        //...
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting that `Event` is not a proxyable class due to `Event` has no any no-args constructor. Why am I getting this exception now?

Comment: Probably make a new question for that, from this one, there isn't enough info to tell. But my guess is literally what you typed - `Event has no any no-args constructor.`. You need no-arg constructor to be able to do a proxy of anything. And req. scope needs proxies.

Answer (score 1):

The producer may be `@RequestScoped` but the produced bean is `@Dependent`! To make it request scoped as intended, simply annotate the *producer method*:

```
@Produces @RequestScoped
public Event getStripeEvent() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could I remove `@RequestScoped` from class. What does it mean it's dependent?